# Buscar o valor devolvido via REST e inserir em um input

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Estou buscado, via RESTful, o valor de `id` de um usuário cadastrado numa API. Agora tenho que inserir este valor em um *input* HTML. Estou tentando desta forma:

Capturo o valor da variável numa *tag* de parágrafo com a classe (valor) e o id (nome)

e o valor aparece normalmente na tela.

tenho o *input* onde quero inserir este valor que é;

```
<input class="campo" type="text" value="">
```

E tem o JavaScript onde tento fazer essa inserção que é;

```
let novoValor = document.querySelector(".valor").value; 
console.log(novoValor); 
let campo = document.querySelector(".campo");

campo.value = novoValor;
```

Se eu dou um `console.log(novoValor)` aparece no console do navegador isso:

```
<p data-brackets-id="1122" class="valor" id="id">6</p>
```

que é o exato id que estou buscando no momento. Só que no input ao invés de aparecer o valor 6 que é o id do usuário, aparece esta mensagem "undefined"

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, preciso da resposta em javascript e não em frameworks

Comment: Como é que está sua API ?

Comment: Elemento de parágrafo, `<p>`, não possui o atributo `value`. Se você quer pegar o conteúdo da *tag*, use o atributo `innerHTML`

Comment: Eu estou capturando o id e fazendo uma variável com ele. Se você ler um pouco melhor vai ver que estou inserindo ele num input que tem um value

Comment: Não estou interessado em colocar o valor no mesmo lugar que estou buscando o mesmo valor

Comment: se o valor já está na tag <p> para que eu precisaria colocar ele lá novamente?

Comment: @LR10 minha api fica on-line, é em java e não fui em quem fez

Comment: Com `document.querySelector(".valor")` você busca um elemento `<p>` no DOM e tenta acessar o valor de `value` dele. Elementos `<p>` não possuem o atributo `value`, por isso aparece `undefined`. Pesquise sobre o `innerHTML` que entenderá o que fazer.

Comment: Tudo bem @AndersonCarlosWoss, meu código que está tentando fazer a inserção é este     <script>
  
    let novoValor = document.querySelector(".valor").value;
      console.log(novoValor);
    let campo = document.querySelector(".campo");
    
    campo.value = novoValor;
  
  </script> onde eu coloco o innerHTML. Tipo que eu não sei mesmo de frontend, esse é o motivo de recorrer ao fórum

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz, basta alterar `document.querySelector(".valor").value` por `document.querySelector(".valor").innerHTML`